# Scanner User-Input move cursor between brackets

Tags: java

I want to have a simple user -input  using by a java.util.Scanner. The problem is , I want to take my answer between Strings. The input will be a char. It will be a simple y/n question.
And the answer of user should see like this.

Do you want to continue? y/n : (_)

the place that I pointed with '_' ,should be the place, where the user input will be taken(between brackets).

thanx for ur answers.

Burak

Comment: I found it guys :)


System.out.printf("<y>/<n> : ( ) \b\b\b");
    
sc.next().charAt(0);

thanx any way

Answer (score 0):

I may be speaking out of turn, but I don't believe standard java console I/O supports this.  You may want to check out JCurses(http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) or some other graphics utility